# Showing rows of zeros when using .N

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table that roughly looks something like this:

```
DT <- data.table(disease = c(0,0,1,1,1,1),
   hospital = c(2,2,4,3,3,2))
```

Each row corresponds to a person admitted to a hospital. "hospital" is the ID number of the hospital, "disease" is the status of a specific disease. 1=sick, 0=not sick.

I want to count how many sick people there are on each hospital, also counting hospitals with no sick people AND also counting hospitals that aren't in this specific data.table, so that I am able to specify how many hospitals should be in my final table.

By using: 
`DT[disease==1, .N, keyby= hospital]`
i get

```
   hospital N
1:        2 2
2:        3 1
3:        4 1
```

But If f.ex. I want the number of hospitals to be five, my resulting data.table (it does not have to end up being a data.table, it could also be a matrix) would look something like this:

```
   hospital N
1:        1 0
2:        2 2
2:        3 1
3:        4 1
5:        5 0
```

Preferably sorted. It could also be a vector of N's as long as it counts hospitals with zero incidents (but then it definitely has to be sorted).

I have a rather big set of data (also with other columns) and this is going on in a loop, so it has to be rather fast.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm confused. Why is `N = 2` for `hospital = 2`? There are two entries with `disease = 0` and one with `disease = 1` for that hospital. How does that give a count of 2?

Answer (score 1):

I assume there is a mistake because sample data and expected output don't seem to match (see my comment above).

That aside, you could use `table`

```
table(DT[, hospital := factor(hospital, 1:5)])[2, ]
#1 2 3 4 5
#0 1 2 1 0
```

Or perhaps you want the sum of `disease = 0` and `disease = 1` counts?

```
colSums(table(DT[, hospital := factor(hospital, 1:5)]))
#1 2 3 4 5
#0 3 2 1 0
```

In both cases, the return object is a named `int` vector.

Comment: @sindri_baldur That still doesn't match OPs expected output (see my comment above). Also, a vector as the return object is ok according to OP.

Comment: There was a mistake in my last comment. This should work (to get a data.table, but I see now OP is ok with a vector), `DT[disease == 1, .(table(factor(hospital, 1:5)))][, .(hospital = V1, N)]`. Pretty sure the expected ouput by OP just has this one typo.

Comment: @sindri_baldur Sure, or simply `data.table(hospital = 1:5, N = table(DT[, hospital := factor(hospital, 1:5)])[2, ])`.

Comment: Oh, yeah there's a typo. I edited the table a few times. Forgot to pay attention to which one I ended up using. 

Both of the answers do what It is supposed to do. Thank you very much, it helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
DT[.(hospital = 1:5, disease = 1), on = .(hospital, disease), .N, by = .EACHI
   ][, .(hospital, N)]

   hospital N
1:        1 0
2:        2 1
3:        3 2
4:        4 1
5:        5 0
```